# Membership API ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

It is necessary to register as soon as this user directly login

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Membership.CreateUser(FNBox.Text, PassBox.Text, EmailBox.Text);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(FNBox.Text);
    }
```

Error:
**"Could not find the resource.
Description: HTTP 404. Perhaps the desired resource (or one of its dependencies of components) is removed, has a different name or is temporarily unavailable. Look at the following URL-address and make sure it is correct.**

**The requested URL: / OrderTest2/login.aspx** "

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control lgnview = (Control)LoginView2.FindControl("LoginForm");
    TextBox usrbox = (TextBox)lgnview.FindControl("UserName");
    TextBox pasbox = (TextBox)lgnview.FindControl("Password");
    string user = usrbox.Text;
    string pass = pasbox.Text;
    if(Membership.ValidateUser(user,pass))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(user);
    }
}
```

This is work normally

Comment: does `/OrderTest2/login.aspx` exist?

Comment: That's a really bad title. What is your question about the "Membership API ASP.NET"?

Answer (score 0):

Your default redirect login page is wrong. As you can see, you are getting a 404 error which means that IIS cannot find your `OrderTest2/login.aspx` page. Verify your path.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **defaultUrl** path in your web.config as below to a valid page path, this will fix the problem.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/OrderTest2/login.aspx" defaultUrl="myCustomLogin.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"  />
</authentication>
```